# inputBox to insert a before input box

Tags: vba, excel, inputbox

I have difficult to insert in a Input ox a input that before was asked:

Because the first input was : what is your name

```
Dim myValue As Variant

myValue = InputBox("insert the number", "Hello ***T3***")

Range("T4").Value = myValue

End Sub
```

T3 is the cell numeber

Can you help me plese?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
myValue = InputBox("insert the number", "Hello " & Range("T3").Value)
```

Comment: thank you!. It is give a error: "Only comments may appear afther End Sub, End Function, or End Property"

Comment: Check you don’t have anything after your end sub